# Bubble button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to know how to create a button that I can move around the sides of the screen inside my app.

I'm currently trying to use draggable inside the MaterialApp builder for keeping the same bubble in all screens but I get:

"The most common way to add an Overlay to an application is to include a MaterialApp or Navigator widget in the runApp() call."

This is what I'm talking about: [image: 1]

Comment: do you found how to bubble button if the app in the background like the screen shoot above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

This should give you some basic idea.

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (_, child) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            child,
            Positioned(
              left: _offset.dx,
              top: _offset.dy,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) => setState(() => _offset += details.delta),
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Page1')),
            body: Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Page2'))),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Go to Page2'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```